# Ploting timeseries graph with ploty

Tags: python, plotly

I have some transaction data containing product sold, datetime and value.
I am organizing such information on a daily graph with 5min cumulative value using plotly.
I can create 100% "ok" graph like this :

```
df = teste.groupby([pd.Grouper(key='data', freq='5min', origin='start_day', convention = 'start', dropna = True, sort=True, closed = 'left')]).aggregate({'gmv' :'sum'}).reset_index()
df.sort_values(by='data', inplace=True)
dti = pd.date_range(df['data'].min().normalize(), df['data'].max(), freq='5min', name='data')
df = df.set_index('data').reindex(dti, fill_value=0).reset_index()
df["cum_sale"]=df.groupby([df['data'].dt.date])['gmv'].cumsum(axis=0)

df['time'] = df['data'].dt.time
df['date'] = df['data'].dt.date
    
fig = px.line(df, x="time", y="cum_sale", color="date")
fig.show()
```

This code achieve this graphics

[image]

Recently I have some days where there were a discount over some products, so I want to visualize such days in a different color of all other.

I´ve just added this code to set which days are promotional e which are not.

```
df['promo'] = False
df.loc[df['date'].isin([date(2023,6,16), date(2023,6,17), date(2023,6,18)]), 'promo'] = True
fig = px.line(df, x="time", y="cum_sale", color="promo")
fig.show()
```

After that, I just try to plot using the "promo" column for color instead of "date", but ploty create some crazy lines over the graphic and I can´t remove it.

[image]

Any tip?

### Update

After updating my code with the answer, the weird lines do disappear

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without a minimum reproducible code it's a bit hard to be sure, but I think the following is happening:

In the first graph, because you assign colors to a date, PX splits these into different traces and assigns a different color to each trace. If you are familiar with plotly.graph_objects (go.Figure()) this should sound familiar.

Now in the second version, you no longer implicitly separate the days anymore. The variables that go into the graph are "time", "cum_sale" and "promo". Nothing about date. So in this case it splits the traces over "promo", because you told it to. So what it did is create two graphs: one for TRUE and one for FALSE. And the straight lines are the line graph connecting the end of one day to the start of the next.

The most controlled solution is to switch to plotly.go.Figure() plots.

A quick fix would be to assign different symbols to the PX graphs, so it splits over another variable.

Change this line:

```
fig = px.line(df, x="time", y="cum_sale", color="date")
```

into

```
fig = px.line(df, x="time", y="cum_sale", color="promo", symbol="date")
```

See if that works.

Comment: Thanks! I does work. My remaining question is why does the visual of the graphic changes after adding the symbols. Take a look at my question update!

Comment: About graph_objects, I am a newbie at plotly and using plotly express has been the only way I´ve been achieving graphics close to what i desire! lol!

Comment: I also started with express, which is great for easy plotting. GO allows more complex plots by manual settings. The reason of the change is that each parameter (color, symbol) creates a split in the data. Your first graph was only split over TRUE and FALSE, which you signed to color. The Symbol parameter added a split over DATE. Without these splits everything is assigned to a single trace. That trace consists of consecutive days which keeps going back to 1 after the end of one day, and the race then connects the end of one day to the start of the next.